# How can I count values based on dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula that will count the numbers in columns C:F but only for the rows with a date in column B that is within the last 5 days. Ideally on any given Friday it would be counting the numbers for Monday - Friday.

I know excel can do things like this but I'm not very familiar with it. I've tried a couple of different ways that I've found online such as:

```
=SUMIFS(C3:F1000,B3:B1000,">="&TODAY()-5)
```

However, I'm getting an "Error in Value" and I'm not sure what's wrong. This was almost exactly what I saw in an example I found online.

[image: Example]

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-one-criteria-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B1000>=TODAY()-5)*(C3:F1000))
```